# Unable to extend ActiveRecord from within gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport, activesupport-concern

I'd like my gem to add a method to my AR classes that would enable some functionality:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enable_my_uber_features :blah
end
```

For this, within my_uber_gem/lib/uber_gem.rb, I attempt the following:

```
# my_uber_gem/lib/uber_gem.rb

require "active_support"
# ...
require "uber/extensions"
# ...

ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do

  class ActiveRecord::Base
    include Uber::Extensions
  end
end
```

In uber/extensions.rb I have:

```
# my_uber_gem/lib/uber/extensions.rb

require 'active_support/concern'
module Uber
    module Extensions
        extend ActiveSupport::Concern
        
        instance_methods do
            def foo
                p :bar
            end
        end

        class_methods do
            def enable_my_uber_features(value)
                p value
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Now I'd expect to see a blah in the console when instantiating an User, however I get an error:

```
[...] `method_missing': undefined method `enable_my_uber_features' for User:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I've tried including Uber::Extensions into ApplicationRecord instead of ActiveRecord::Base, no luck.

I've also tried extend `Uber::Extensions`, no luck.

I've also tried defining a `module ClassMethods` from within `Uber::Extensions` the extending/including, still no luck.

I've also followed this guy's guide by the letter: https://waynechu.cc/posts/405-how-to-extend-activerecord, still no luck.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what ruby on rails version are you using?

Comment: How are you installing this gem? Are you sure this file is being loaded at all?

Comment: Why would you like to extend `ActiveRecord::Base` if you could do the same with `ApplicationRecord`?

Comment: @beniutek I am using Ruby 3 and Rails 6.0. I've tried extending both ActiveRecord::Base and ApplicationRecord with no luck.

Comment: @engineersmnky I've added it in the Gemfile, I'm sure it's loaded because other classes that come with the gem are usable

Comment: If you want to see how we do this in PaperTrail, check out [has_paper_trail.rb](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/has_paper_trail.rb) and [paper_trail/frameworks/active_record.rb](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/frameworks/active_record.rb)

Comment: I've seen that in papertrail and searchkick and a bunch of other gems, I am basically trying to do the same thing. What's odd is that if I extend from the Rails console it works. Just not from the gem/gem.rb file for some reason.

Comment: do you want `enable_my_uber_features` to be a class method or an instance method? You are calling it as a class method in the User class, but you are defining it as an instance method.

Comment: I have never seen really why gems can't just let you explicitly include them instead of monkeypatching their way into the system. You're just saving the end user one line of code.

Comment: @LesNightingill I've updated the code in the question, I tried adding both class and instance methods, nothing gets added from the gem file for some reason

Comment: It looks like it's some sort of cache causing things to misbehave, I've changed foo to bar in the gem's concern file then included the concern into a class from rails console, then when inspecting the class it still shows foo as class method, as opposed to bar :(

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done this is:

```rb
# in my_uber_gem/lib/active_record/base/activerecord_base.rb
require 'uber/extensions'
class ActiveRecord::Base
  include Uber::Extensions
  def baz
    p "got baz"
  end
end

# and in the my_uber_gem/lib/my_uber_gem.rb
module MyUberGem
  require_relative './active_record/base/activerecord_base.rb'
end

# and finally define the extension in my_uber_gem/lib/uber/extensions.rb
require 'active_support/concern'
class Uber
  module Extensions
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    def foobar(val)
      p val
    end
  end
end

# now you can do
User.first.foobar("qux") #=> "qux"
User.first.baz #=> "got baz"
```

Comment: Placing the `require_relative` inside the Module definition does not change its scope.

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm not sure what you mean. But anyway I have this working as shown.

Comment: I mean that placing the `require_relative` inside `MyUberGem` does not contain it within this Module's scope. It has the same impact as placing it outside of the Module or anywhere else.  [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/requirescope#main.rb)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Rails was caching my local gem I was working on, and any changes I made to any gem files were only visible in a new app or after rebuilding the entire machine.

I was able to turn this off so it will reload the gem on every console reload:

```
  # config/environments/development.rb
  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/../my_uber_gem/lib)
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.explicitly_unloadable_constants << 'MyUberGem'
```